# Convert Julian date to normal date and time using python

Tags: python, date, julian-date

I want to convert a Julian date to normal date and time. My start year is 2010.1.1 00:00:00 and the part of the code where I am processing the dates is the following:

```
import astropy.time
import dateutil.parser
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
dt = dateutil.parser.parse('2010.01.01')
time1 = astropy.time.Time(dt)
jd=time1.jd
print(jd)

datetime_start=266065955.675 #seconds from 2010.1.1 00:00:00
datetime_startjd=(datetime_start/24./60./60.)+jd
print(datetime_startjd)

from __future__ import print_function, division
from PyAstronomy import pyasl

print("The decimal year %10.5f correspond to " % datetime_startjd+ \
  pyasl.decimalYearGregorianDate(datetime_startjd, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"))
print(" ... or equivalently (y, m, d, h, m, s, ms): ", \
  pyasl.decimalYearGregorianDate(datetime_startjd, "tuple"))
```

I am getting the error:

> ValueError: year 2458276 is out of range

Can someone please suggest me with an accurate code or way which converts this Julian date to normal date and time?

Answer (score 0):

i Found what i needed using the following code, in case someone wants to use it:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.time import Time

times = [ '2010-01-01T00:00:00']
t = Time(times, format='isot', scale='utc')
juliant=t.jd
print(juliant)

datetime_start=265633590.42
datetime_startjd=(datetime_start/24./60./60.)+juliant
print(datetime_startjd)

time2=Time('2458271.96285208',format='jd')
time3=time2.iso
print(time3)

datetime_length=1.0800000429153442
cover_time=((datetime_start+datetime_length)/24./60./60.)+juliant
print(cover_time)
cover_time=Time(cover_time,format='jd')
cover_time=cover_time.iso
print(cover_time)
```